# Preventing Helm C-k from deleting entire minibuffer

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

Probably a very simple answer, but when I use `helm-find-files`, I often accidentally hit C-k (`helm-delete-minibuffer-contents`) instead of C-j (`helm-execute-persistent-action`), deleting the entire minubuffer instead of navigating into a directory.

I noticed that the variable `helm-delete-minibuffer-contents-from-point` exists, which when, the documentation states,

`is non-‘nil’, delete minibuffer contents from point instead of deleting all. Giving a prefix arg reverses this behavior. When at the end of minibuffer, deletes all.`

So I've tried in my init to set

`(setq helm-delete-minibuffer-contents-from-point t)`

but still C-k produces exactly the same behaviour of deleting the entire minibuffer. What gives? Am I doing something totally stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That variable does something else. In this case you want to unbind C-k:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-k") nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! That does the job. :)